# Breaking up multiple google form entries in R

Tags: r, google-forms

I have a csv file with results from an online Google Form that I am using to create graphs in R. There is one question on the form that allows for multiple responses, and people can write in a response. The way Google Forms is creating the CSV is by putting all answers into one row. Here is an example of a few rows:

| Date | Change in treatment |
| --- | --- |
| 1/4 | Started new medication, changed dose |
| 1/5 | Started new medication |
| 1/6 | Stopped medication, Started new medication, New diagnosis |
| 1/7 | New diagnosis |

I would like to create a bar chart that summarizes all the individual responses to the question, but in order to do that I need to separate each response from each row (each response is separated by a comma). Is there a way I can code this in R or Python? Or should I be dealing with Google Forms itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyverse)
separated.data <- data %>% 
  separate_rows(Change.in.treatment,sep = ", ")
separated.data
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Date  Change.in.treatment   
  <chr> <chr>                 
1 1/4   Started new medication
2 1/4   changed dose          
3 1/5   Started new medication
4 1/6   Stopped medication    
5 1/6   Started new medication
6 1/6   New diagnosis         
7 1/7   New diagnosis
```

From here, you can easily make a bar chart with `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(data = separated.data, aes(x = Change.in.treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

[image]

Sample Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("1/4", "1/5", "1/6", "1/7"), Change.in.treatment = c("Started new medication, changed dose", 
"Started new medication", "Stopped medication, Started new medication, New diagnosis", 
"New diagnosis")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```